# How can I make a killcounter?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Win. 10 edition just got a scoreboard command, and I have no idea how to use it. Can someone tell me how to make a scoreboard that keeps track of each players kills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bedrock Edition (which Windows 10 Edition is part of) only just got scoreboards. Currently, scoreboards can only be modified manually by commands. You'll have to wait for the devs to add the different scoreboard types that are available in Java Edition, such as `playerKillCount`.